# Get data from last 40 months

Tags: oracle

I have written a query to display the number of sales that were made in the last 40 months for the below table:

TABLE NAME: Sale

```
SALEID  SID  SLDATE
1001    1    01-JAN-14
1002    5    02-JAN-14
1003    4    01-FEB-14
1004    1    01-MAR-14
1005    2    01-FEB-14
1006    1    01-JUN-15
```

```
SELECT COUNT(SLDATE)  AS SALE_COUNT 
FROM Sale 
WHERE SLDATE <= ADD_MONTHS(SLDATE, -40);   /*MY QUERY LOGIC*/
```

ERROR: YOUR QUERY MATCHES OUTPUT RESULT, BUT THERE ARE LOGICAL ERRORS.

Answer (score 3):

The condition `SLDATE <= ADD_MONTHS(SLDATE, -40)` will never be true because it compares the value of `SLDATE` with a date 40 months, before **that** date. You probably want to use today's date instead:

```
select count(*) as sale_count 
from sale 
where sldate >= add_months(SYSDATE, -40);
```

Comment: Thank you for your Reply I tried the above query it results "SALE_COUNT = 0" but it did not match with the expected result (EXPECTED RESULT: SALE_COUNT=1).

Comment: @Mr.AI It that expected results works only with 55 months not 40,you can calculate number of months between two dates  `select months_between(sysdate,'01-JUN-15') from dual;`(first set NLS_DATE_FORMAT in session)